# how to multiply 2 24 bit numbers in assembly

Tags: assembly, 68hc12

I am trying to multiply 2 24 bit numbers M and N and store the product in p at memory location `$1100`.

The expected output when I do md 1100 should be  `$07336BF94116` but I am getting  `07 1A 48 58 - 41 16 8D 0C - 92 C2 82 85 - 48 B9 79 03`

I am not sure what is wrong with my program but any help would greatly be appreciated.

```
org $1000
M   dc.b    $12,$34,$56 ; define the value of M
N   dc.b    $65,$43,$21 ; define the value of N
    org $1100 ; define the memory addresses for P
P   ds.b    6 ; the product should be $07336BF94116 when md 1100
    org $2000 ;    
    ldy M+1
    ldd N+1
    emul    
    std P+4
    ldaa    M
    ldab    N
    mul 
    std P
    ldab    M
    ldaa    #0
    ldy N+1
    addd    P+2
    xgdy    
    adcb    P+1
    adca    P
    ldab    N
    ldaa    #0
    ldy M+1
    addd    P+2
    xgdy    
    adcb    P+1
    adca    P   
    swi 
    end
```

I am uploading this code to a dragon12-plus2.

Comment: Single step the code to verify each partial result. Also, comment your code especially if you want others to help.

Comment: "Assembly language (asm) programming questions. BE SURE TO ALSO TAG with the processor and/or instruction set you're using, as well as the assembler. "

Comment: It's even unclear why you give the actual result as 64 bits instead of 48. The least significant 16 bits of the result should be correct as that is the direct output of the first `emul`.